# How to break quarterly data into monthly using certain formula in R?

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

Dears

I am trying to breakdown quarterly data into monthly data using R. I am not concerned about dates as I can generate a vector of months corresponding to values without problems. The problem is with the vector of values and imputing the missing data. See the example below:

```
Quarter Value
2010-Q1 10
2010-Q2 15
2010-Q3 18
2010-Q4 12
```

The new data set should look like the following

```
Month   Value
2010-3  10
2010-4  11.67
2010-5  13.34
2010-6  15
2010-7  16
2010-8  17
2010-9  18
2010-10 16
2010-11 14
2010-12 12
```

Now, the months within each quarter are filled using the following formula

```
The first month of the quarter[i] = The previous quarter value [i-1] + ((The difference between the quarter [i] and [i-1])/3)
The second month of the quarter[i] = The previous quarter value [i-1] + 2*((The difference between the quarter [i] and [i-1])/3)
```

For example:

2020-Q1 = 10

2020-Q2 = 15

Difference/3 =  5/3

2020-April = 10 + diff

2020-May = 10 + 2*diff

2020-June = 15 (end of the quarter stays the same) or can be calculated as 10 + 3*diff

I am wondering how to generate a new variable that can break down the values as mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: The purported duplicate does not have any answers that answer this question as stated.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Convert the input to a zoo series `z` with `yearqtr` index (which directly represents year and quarter without month or day) and then pad out with NAs and apply `na.approx` to fill them in linearly giving `Value`.  Assuming that the series is regularly spaced we can just convert the first index value to `yearmon` (which directly represents a year and month without day) using a frequency of 12 months per year.  Finally, either leave it as `Value` or else use the last line to convert it back to data frame `DF2`.  Another possibility would be to use `as.ts(Value)` to convert it to a `ts` series.

Note that `yearmon` class displays as shown below but represents year and month internally as year plus a fraction equal to 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec so `as.integer(time(Value))` will give the year and `cycle(time(Value))` will give the month number (Jan = 1, ..., Dec = 12).

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = function(x) as.yearqtr(x, "%Y-Q%q"))
Value <- zooreg(na.approx(c(t(cbind(z, NA, NA)))), 
  start = as.yearmon(start(z)), freq = 12)
DF2 <- fortify.zoo(Value) # optional
```

giving:

```
> DF2
      Index    Value
1  Jan 2010 10.00000
2  Feb 2010 11.66667
3  Mar 2010 13.33333
4  Apr 2010 15.00000
5  May 2010 16.00000
6  Jun 2010 17.00000
7  Jul 2010 18.00000
8  Aug 2010 16.00000
9  Sep 2010 14.00000
10 Oct 2010 12.00000
```

Graphically it looks like this:

```
plot(Value, type = "o")
```

(continued after plot)
[image: screenshot]

**2)** A second method starting with `z` from (1) is to first create the output `yearmon` time sequence `tt`, convert the time index of `z` to `yearmon` giving `z.ym` and then merge them generating NA's and finally apply `na.approx` to fill them in.

```
tt <- seq(as.yearmon(start(z)), as.yearmon(end(z)), 1/12)
z.ym <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, c)
Value <- na.approx(merge(z.ym, zoo(, tt)))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Quarter Value
2010-Q1 10
2010-Q2 15
2010-Q3 18
2010-Q4 12"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am more interested in the value column. I can add a time series variable to it without a problem. My question maybe is not clear. How do I change the Value variable alone to the form I mentioned in my question. Forget about the time.